# Thinkpad x240 requires three fingers to scroll, only after suspend

Tags: linux, opensuse, touchpad, openbox, thinkpad

Every time I suspend, when I start up again I can't scroll with two fingers but I have to use three. Does anyone know how to fix this? It works after restart.

My system is a Thinkpad x240 running openSUSE + OpenBox and here's what I get when I run `libinput list-devices` for the trackpad *after suspend and wake up*.

```
Device:           SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event17
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             109x96mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   none
Rotation:         n/a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read bug report [Two-finger scrolling no longer works after resuming from suspend](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1722478).

Possible fix: Add `psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in your `/etc/default/grub`.

Example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: `update-grub` isn't a command on openSUSE, but the rest of the answer is correct and helped me fix this, thank you so much! Can you please elaborate on what exactly that does?

Comment: Default on 4.12 kernels (and above?) is communication via RMI4 over SMBus and `psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0` reverts it back to the old style PS/2 behaviour. See [comment 42](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1722478/comments/42) of the bug report or https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196719.
I never noticed this bug on my X250 and T440s as I only use the trackpoint (touchpad disabled in bios) :)