# T440S Touchpad disabled at each reboot. I found that manually reloading the synaptics driver fixes it. How do I make the change permanent in Kubuntu?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, kubuntu, synaptic, modprobe

After every reboot, I need to run `sudo rmmod psmouse` and `sudo modprobe -v psmouse` to re-enable the touchpad. Otherwise, double finger scrolling doesn't work and only a few areas of the pad work, much like a mouse, `xinput list-props "ID"` also shows the touchpad using `libinput` instead of `synaptics` and the system settings displays "Touchpad not found".

I tried adding configuration files in `/etc/modprobe.d` and `/etc/modules-load.d` but it is still not working.

In the configuration files, I simply wrote the module name `psmouse` and edited `rc.local` and `modules.conf` in `/etc` with:

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

None of this worked so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Try if booting with kernel option [psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508813/332764) fixes the touchpad.

Comment: Just tried that but that didn't fix it either. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I used crontab to schedule these commands at reboot.
To do this I opened file **crontab** as superuser in folder **etc**:

```
sudo gedit /etc/crontab
```

Then I inserted a line at the end, so that the commands are executed as root (applied to every user):

```
@reboot root modprobe -e psmouse && modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

I hope it helps!